# Update sum on table change (tr add, remove, focus, type...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I'm looking for the best way to trigger (call) a function which will sum all the input fields in all table rows. 
The problem is, that the field can be manipulated manually (by typing) or with a function - value written to them (which does not trigger an event).

I would like that the sum function would trigger on add/remove row (tr), keypress, focusout...

Btw: i'm cloning the table rows, so they are created dynamically.

Thanks!

```
$(".val_field:input").live("focusout", function(){
    val = parseFloat( $(this).val() );
    sum += isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
    $("#sum").val( sum );
});
```

Comment: You said that you're creating the table rows dynamically now. What's preventing you from calling your sum function there?

Comment: Your sample code appears to add the input value to the sum every time it's edited, rather than keeping the actual total :-?

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to know if there was a more elegant method than calling Sum function from number of different places (functions)... 
This code was just a sample...working code...it's what i needed at the moment.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but any answer can be useful

```
function recount(el){
    var sum = 0;
    el.parents('table').find('.val_field:input').each(function(){
        var val = parseFloat( $(this).val() );
        sum += isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
    });
    $("#sum").val( sum );
}

$('table').on('keypress blur', '.val_field:input', function(){
    recount($(this));
});
```

Of course, you can apply `recount()` on row removal too (that's why I factorized it).